# Are extra batteries bad for the phone?

Tags: battery, nokia-lumia-820

I have a Lumia 820, and use a lot of data on it as well as plenty gaming. Of course, fast battery drainage is a result. The battery always gets eaten up by mid-day every day. I was thinking about getting some extra batteries, but I am not sure if it might bad for my phone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you are running out of battery where you cannot finish the day without the phone dying, having a replacement battery you can swap out will not damage the phone at all as long as you purchase a suitable replacement. In fact, this has been a common practice amongst business users and a complaint about many high end phones which tend to not have replaceable batteries.

Nokia even sells [portable](http://www.nokia.com/global/products/accessory/dc-18/) [battery](http://www.nokia.com/global/products/accessory/dc-19/) [chargers](http://www.nokia.com/global/products/accessory/dc-50/) if you do not want to carry an extra battery around.

Comment: I carry a third-party portable charger and really love having it.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. I don't have a Lumia 820, but I do have an extra battery that I switch to when my Lumia 822 dies. The battery life is much improved, and my phone still work good enough for me now.